# Quantum Mechanics Basics: product space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, harmonic-oscillator, hilbert-space

Consider a coupled harmonic oscillator with their position given by $x_1$ and $x_2$. Say the normal coordinates $x_{\pm}={1\over\sqrt{2}} (x_1\pm x_2)$, in which the harmonic oscillators decouple, exist.

When you quantize this theory, the corresponding operators are $\hat x_1,~
\hat x_2,~ \hat x_{\pm}$. The operators  $\hat x_1,~\hat x_2$ commutes and 
$$\hat x_{\pm}\equiv{1\over\sqrt{2}} (\hat x_1 \otimes \hat 1_2 \pm \hat 1_1\otimes \hat x_2),$$ 
where $\hat 1_1,~\hat 1_2$ are identity operators. 
So this operator $\hat x_{\pm}$ acts in a direct product basis given by 
$$|x_1,x_2\rangle=|x_1\rangle \otimes |x_2\rangle$$
where $|x_1\rangle$ and $|x_2\rangle$ are eigen states of $\hat x_1$ and $\hat x_2$ respectively.

**But the state $|x_1,x_2\rangle$ is eigenstate of both $\hat x_{\pm}$.**

> **How can we construct unique eigenstates of the operator $\hat x_{\pm}$ in the basis $|x_1,x_2\rangle$? Or is it that it is not possible?**

Comment: Nitpicking: "direct product" ($\times$) $\neq$ "tensor product" ($\otimes$) for [vector spaces or more generally modules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product#Direct_product_of_modules). In fact, for finite number of spaces being "(co)producted," the direct product is equivalent to the "direct sum" ($\oplus$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both $\hat{x}_{\pm}$ commute with both $\hat{x}$ (product with identity). So they do (as you verified) share a common set of eigenvectors.

In this case the set contains any product of two position eigenstates. That's why any state $|x,y\rangle$ is an eigenvector of all four of your operators.

So I guess the final answer is: No, that's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

As you note, the states $|x_1, x_2\rangle$ are eigenstates of $x_\pm$;
$$
  \hat x_\pm |x_1, x_2\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x_1 + x_2)|x_1,x_2\rangle
$$
Moreover, these states form an orthonormal basis (in the Dirac sense) for the tensor product Hilbert space.  It follows that every eigenvector of either of these operators must be a scalar multiple of one of the states $|x_1, x_2\rangle$.

To see this, let's suppose that there is a state $|\psi\rangle$ that is not a scalar multiple of one of the vectors $|x_1, x_2\rangle$, then there exists some other $|x_1',x_2'\rangle$ and nonzero complex numbers $a$ and $b$ for which
$$
  |\psi\rangle = a|x_1,x_2\rangle + b|x_1',x_2'\rangle
$$
and therefore
$$
  \hat x_\pm|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(a(x_1 + x_2)|x_1,x_2\rangle + b(x_1'+x_2')|x_1',x_2'\rangle\right)
$$
this state is not an eigenvector of $x_{\pm}$ unless $x_1'+x_2' = x_1 + x_2$.

**Edit.** In response to the comment below, the following statement is false:

> in this basis both eigen states of x± are same. So it implies x^+=x^−

Two operators having a simultaneous eigenbasis does not mean that they are equal!  What matters is the action of these operators on each of these basis states.  In the case at hand, the *eigenvalues* of $\hat x_+$ and $\hat x_-$ are distinct, so we can clearly see that they are distinct operators.

Comment: I agree with you and the answer before by Bruce Connor.

Comment: @user27470 Cool.  Does this response not answer the question?  Perhaps I misinterpreted it?

Comment: I agree with you and the answer before by Bruce Connor.  To be more clear about my question let us consider the product hilbert space is called $H=H_1 \otimes H_2$. Clearly $\hat x_{\pm}$ are operators in the hilbert space $H$. One of the possible basis of $H$ is $|x_1,x_2>$. What is confusing me is that I thought that every opertor eigenstate in $H$ can be expressed as linear combination of its basis states, here one choice is the simple states $|x_1,x_2>$. But in this basis both eigen states of $x_{\pm}$ are same. So it implies $\hat x_+=\hat x_-$. But we know this cannot be true!

Comment: The first response went by mistake. You are correct. I agree with you but it does not answer my question

Comment: @user27470 See my edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Somehow I forgot a operator is defined by its eigenvalues and eigenvectors. I agree it is wrong to think it is determined by one of them. Thanks again as this silly confusion was giving me pain in some other calculation.

Comment: @user27470 Sure thing. Cheers.